# Find angle of circle line intersection

Tags: geometry

I need an equation for finding the angle (or coordinates) of a circle and line intersection, **the line is always parallel to either the x or y axis** and intersecting 2 points on the circle:

(Example)
[image]

Using this in some code so separate equations for if the line is parallel to x or y axis are fine.

**It has to be efficient so I don't need the solution for line pointing in any other direction than parallel to either axis**.

**(Edit)**
To clarify, the radius of the circle, and position of the line are known.
And oh yeah, whoops, that x coordinate shouldn't be a "?"

Comment: The number of question marks in the image linked to in the body of the question preclude the possibility of finding any angle. You need to have at least *some* information about this line of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, this question is pretty straightforward. Split it into two questions: either the line is horizontal, or the line is vertical.
For each of these, run the following algorithm:

1. Does the line intersect at all? I assume you can check for this.
2. Does the line intersect once? If it does:

   - If the line is vertical ($x=c$), the angle is either $0$ degrees or $180$ degrees. $\theta = 0$ if $c>h$, where $h$ is the $x$-coordinate of the center of the circle. Otherwise, $\theta=180$.
   - If the line is horizontal ($y=c$), the angle is either $90$ degrees or $270$ degrees. $\theta = 90$ if $c>h$, where $h$ is the $y$-coordinate of the center of the circle. Otherwise, $\theta=270$.
3. Otherwise, the line intersections twice. I'll explain the vertical case, and you can figure out the horizontal case.

The equation of the line is $x=c$. The equation of the circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ I'm going to assume for the sake of simplicity that the circle is centered at $(0,0)\implies c^2+y^2=r^2$. Now, we want to solve for the $y$ values solving $y=\pm \sqrt{r^2-c^2}$ This is an easy task for your computer.

After that, you have to $(x,y)$ coordinates: the angle from the origin is simply $\tan{y/x}$. I can't quite tell from your picture which angle you're trying to get, but it'll be a matter of using very simple trig identities.

Answer (score 2):

If the centre of the circle is $x_0,y_0$, its radius is $r$ and the line has $x=c$ then the coordinates of intersection are  $$(c, y_0 - \sqrt{r^2 -(x_0-c)^2})$$ and 
$$(c, y_0 + \sqrt{r^2 -(x_0-c)^2})$$

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need to compute the actual intersection points of the line and the circle to determine this angle. If you draw a perpendicular segment from the center of the circle to the line, you can see that the cosine of half the sector angle is equal to the length of this segment divided by the radius.

To put this in concrete terms, let the circle be centered at $(x_c,y_c)$ with radius $r>0$. For a vertical line $x=c$, we then have $$\cos{\frac\theta2}={|c-x_c|\over r}$$ so $$\theta=2\arccos{|c-x_c|\over r}.$$ Of course, if $|c-x_c|>r$, the line doesn’t intersect the circle. For a horizontal line $y=c$, replace $x_c$ with $y_c$.